# URL Redirecting issue does not redirect on server

Tags: php, redirect

I've fully functional website works fine on my site on my localhost wamp server but i upload the same file into the server on 1&1 the redirect does not work. the code is below

```
<?php require_once('../model/class.user.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('../model/class.person.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('../model/class.session.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('../model/class.loginrecord.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('../controller/general_functions.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('../controller/utility_functions.php'); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    if(isset($_POST['checkUser'])){



        $usrnme = htmlspecialchars($_POST['un']);
        $paswrd = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pwd']);

        if(!empty($usrnme) && !empty($paswrd)){

            //verify user credentials 
            $foundUser = User::verify(array($usrnme, $paswrd));


            if($foundUser){ //if user found in DB
                //$errors[] = "Username : found<br />";

                $UID            = $foundUser->id;
                $userRole       = $foundUser->role;
                $userPersonID   = $foundUser->person_id;//user_person_id has stored the reference to person's table

                $ip =   getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')?:
                        getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
                        getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')?:
                        getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
                        getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')?:
                        getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')?: "UNKNOWN";

                LoginRecord::save(array(null, $foundUser->id, getCurrentDateTime(), $ip));

                $findPerson     = Person::findByID($userPersonID);//find the user based on the 
                $userFN         = Person::fullName($findPerson);//find the full name of the person

                $session->setValues(md5('loginStatus'), encrypt('true'));
                $session->setValues(md5('userID'), encrypt($UID));
                $session->setValues(md5('userFullName'), encrypt($userFN));

                if($userRole == ROLE_ADCMIN)
                {
                    $session->setValues(md5('role'), encrypt(ROLE_ADCMIN));
                    redirectTO('admin/dashboard.php');
                }
                elseif ($userRole == ROLE_AGENT) 
                {
                    $session->setValues(md5('role'), encrypt(ROLE_AGENT));
                    redirectTO('agent/index.php');
                }
                elseif ($userRole == ROLE_OTHER) 
                {
                    redirectTO('superuser/index.php');
                }

            } else {

                $errors[] = "Sorry Username/Password not valid <br />";

            }//end if($foundUser) 

        } else {

            $errors[] = "Text fields are empty.";

        }


    }
```

the function that redirect the page is below:

```
function redirectTO($url = null){
    if($url != null){
        header("Location:{$url}");
        exit();
    }
}
```

I've everything i could but it just does not work show blank page... can you please help me get out of this mess... do you have any idea?

Regards

Comment: what are the versions of php running locally and on your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `<?php ob_start(); ?>` at the very start of the page and use `<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>` at the very end of the page.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you are trying to redirect AFTER you have already outputted data. Headers must be sent before any output is sent to the browser.

Your HTML here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
```

is being outputted before your redirectTo function is called.

Also, you are missing an opening PHP tag after your HTML.

Comment: but how come the same code work without any issue on my localhost

Comment: btw where am i outputing the data?

Comment: @Sharif Updated the answer. You are outputting the data with your HTML.

Comment: You are also missing a PHP tag?

Comment: i have that in actual code just could'nt copy it properly

Comment: is there any way to forcefully redirect to another page

Comment: Maybe you have output_buffering enabled on your local machine but not on your producting server.

Comment: so if i disable output_buffering disabled then it wont work on my local machine?

Answer (score 1):

May be use only `$url` .. don't set `$url=null`

```
function redirectTO($url){
    if($url != null){
        header("Location:{$url}");
        exit();
    }
}
```

let me know if it works ..